# when do anti-piracy measures become malware?

Tags: licensing, piracy

I have been implementing anti-piracy measures in my game and I'm wondering at what point do things start getting shady?

For example, if I know with 10000% certainty that the software is pirated, I was going to do things like crash or freeze the PC of the user. Would this be legal or make my game into malware? I really don't want people running around with pirated copies of my game.

Obviously I am not planning on doing anything that violates user privacy, etc. I will just make the application fail and maybe crash the user's pc.

Comment: Even if the user pirated your game, he can leave a bad review which might be more harmful. And you never know for sure that a pirated game is a lost customer, many would play a pirated version vs not playing it at all

Comment: As an alternative to malware-like behavior: [What happens when pirates play a game development simulator and then go bankrupt because of piracy?](https://www.greenheartgames.com/2013/04/29/what-happens-when-pirates-play-a-game-development-simulator-and-then-go-bankrupt-because-of-piracy/)

Comment: Intentionally crashing the users PC could violate certain anti-hacking laws in some countries. Remember that there is a risk that the user loses data in any programs they still have open, so there is a risk of tangible damage.

Comment: @Pikalek this reminds me of a Valve game were the "pirated" copy had a trigger missing in one map, preventing players from completing the game.

Comment: I know of an instance where a restricted game was released by the publisher to certain sites on release day.

Comment: Note that you actually benefit from the symptoms of a pirated game being subtle. If the piracy protection does something obvious like reboot the computer immediately, then a hacker trying to bypass that protection can easily verify whether they've succeeded. But if it's something like Banjo Kazooie slightly reducing the height of the jump or Arkham Asylum slightly reducing the distance of the glide, the hacker might not notice the protection is still in effect without playing a substantial distance into the game. This massively slows down the process of creating and testing workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

> I was going to do things like crash or freeze the PC of the user. Would this be legal?

No, a program that exceeds its intended purpose is unlawful, whether illegally installed or not.

You are welcome to block your own program as much as you want, but purposefully affecting any other part of the system is illegal.

Sony found this out the hard way with the [BMG copy protection scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal), don't follow suit.

Comment: This answer could be improved by citing the relevant laws & cases mentioned.

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal#Legal_and_financial_problems  Summary: a recall, three class-action lawsuits, and at least four criminal investigations.  Oh, and the rootkit itself was found to be violating copyright.

Comment: original poster here, thanks for the reply. I read the reference you cited and it seems Sony was distributing an entire rootkit, completely undocumented in their EULA. What I hope to do is nothing more than some complex checks to verify with absolute certainty it's a pirated copy, then proceed from there. No higher access priveleges required.

Comment: i think my safest bet right now will just to cause application to fail. i wont touch or interfere with anything else on the system. thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Sony's rootkit was severely messing with the internals of the operating system, though, not just rebooting the computer which is *relatively* harmless (as long as it doesn't happen over and over and over!)

Comment: @Pikalek, You are correct, this is an old case example, but the facts applied to that case,  serves as precedent to any future cases.

Comment: @user253751, Random reboots serve no purpose to the cause, if the the source is unknown.

Comment: I assume that the computer reboots *when the pirated game is played*, not randomly.

Comment: @user253751, That would open you up for a class action lawsuit.  One criminal act justifies another, is not a recognized justification. In most instances.

Comment: @Strom I wasn't trying to suggest that your examples didn't apply. On the contrary, I think this is a potentially good answer & that referencing the relevant facts makes it even more useful. I edited to add the case cited by Mark in the comments - if you were referring to a different situation, please correct my edit.

Comment: @Pikalek, Thank you for your edit. I could could not find a good reliable reference.